# sizeof crashing on iPad 1 but not > iPad 1

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

Consider this code:

```
CGFloat largerLineSpacing = kStreamCellParagraphSpacing;

CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphSettings[1] = {
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &largerLineSpacing }
};
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings, sizeof(*paragraphSettings));
```

This code crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running on an iPad 1 (5.1), but not a 5.1 simulator or an iPad 3 (6.0). My C is weak - am I making a dumb mistake with sizeof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [CTParagraphStyleCreate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTParagraphStyleRef/Reference/reference.html) suggest that its second argument gives the number of `CTParagraphStyleSetting` instances in the `paragraphSettings` array (1 in your case) rather than the size in bytes of the array.

If you change your code to

```
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings, 1);
```

it should work.  Or, if you want to cope with adding more settings in future, you could try

```
int numElems = sizeof(paragraphSettings)/sizeof(paragraphSettings[0]);
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings,
                                                            numElems);
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I wasn't sure why I had to. Comes from not understanding sizeof. Original code was copypasta :).

Comment: Although I'd still like to understand why it works on the other iPad and simulator... just an accident?

Comment: @Tony I'd guess it only works by accident.  If you pass too large a size into CTParagraphStyleCreate, it'll end up reading beyond the stack used by paragraphSettings, treating the other data it finds as CTParagraphStyleSetting instances.  Different iOS versions may have different levels of error checking for the contents of CTParagraphStyleSetting.  Different hosts may have different rules for alignment or marking uninitialised memory.  Basically, if you read off the end of a buffer, the effects will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

static CFIndex const settingCount = 1;

```
CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphSettings[settingCount] = {
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &largerLineSpacing }
};

CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings, settingCount);
```